# Issues updating images in Gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview

I'm building a simple floodit game in android, and am struggling to make the gridview or rather the "ImageAdapterGridView" update the image on click.  When a user clicks on a cell, the game registers the colour of the cell and makes the top left cell the same colour.  The issue being I am unable to make the grid redraw.  All the solutions I have found online seem to be populating the grid in a different way to me.

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int clickedCell;

public String colour = "error";

public int[] numbers = new int[64];

public Context mContext;

public GridView androidGridView;

public Integer[] imageIDs = {
        R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.pink, R.drawable.purple, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange,
        R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.pink, R.drawable.purple, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange,
        R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.pink, R.drawable.purple, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange,
        R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.pink, R.drawable.purple, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange,
        R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.pink, R.drawable.purple, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange,
        R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.pink, R.drawable.purple, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange,
        R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.pink, R.drawable.purple, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange,
        R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.pink, R.drawable.purple, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.orange,
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    Random random= new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int number= random.nextInt(6);
        numbers[i]= number;
    }

    for(int i =0; i < numbers.length; i++)  {
        if(numbers[i]==0)   {
            imageIDs[i] = R.drawable.blue;
        }
        else if(numbers[i]==1)   {
            imageIDs[i] = R.drawable.orange;
        }
        else if(numbers[i]==2)   {
            imageIDs[i] = R.drawable.pink;
        }
        else if(numbers[i]==3)   {
            imageIDs[i] = R.drawable.purple;
        }
        else if(numbers[i]==4)   {
            imageIDs[i] = R.drawable.red;
        }
        else if(numbers[i]==5)   {
            imageIDs[i] = R.drawable.yellow;
        }
    }

    androidGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_android_example);
    androidGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterGridView(this));

    androidGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View v, int position, long id) {

            ImageAdapterGridView IAGV = new ImageAdapterGridView(mContext);

            clickedCell = position;
            if(numbers[clickedCell]==0) {
                imageIDs[0] = R.drawable.blue;
                colour = "blue";
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tile " + (position + 1) + " Selected.  It is " + colour, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                IAGV.getView(0, null, parent);
            }
            else if(numbers[clickedCell]==1)    {
                imageIDs[0] = R.drawable.orange;
                colour = "orange";
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tile " + (position + 1) + " Selected.  It is " + colour, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                IAGV.getView(0, null, parent);
            }
            else if(numbers[clickedCell]==2)    {
                imageIDs[0] = R.drawable.pink;
                colour = "pink";
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tile " + (position + 1) + " Selected.  It is " + colour, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                IAGV.getView(0, null, parent);
            }
            else if(numbers[clickedCell]==3)    {
                imageIDs[0] = R.drawable.purple;
                colour = "purple";
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tile " + (position + 1) + " Selected.  It is " + colour, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                IAGV.getView(0, null, parent);
            }
            else if(numbers[clickedCell]==4)    {
                imageIDs[0] = R.drawable.red;
                colour = "red";
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tile " + (position + 1) + " Selected.  It is " + colour, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                IAGV.getView(0, null, parent);
            }
            else if(numbers[clickedCell]==5)    {
                imageIDs[0] = R.drawable.yellow;
                colour = "yellow";
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tile " + (position + 1) + " Selected.  It is " + colour, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                IAGV.getView(0, null, parent);
            }
        }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapterGridView extends BaseAdapter {

    public ImageAdapterGridView(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageIDs.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView mImageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            mImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));
            mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            mImageView.setPadding(1, 4, 1, 4);
        } else {
            mImageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        mImageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        return mImageView;
    }
}
```

}

This is my main class.  Currently I am trying to re-call the getView() class in the hopes this will re-draw the images, but I don't know if this is possible.  If any other info is needed let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the adapter into a variable:

```
//// extract adapter into a variable instead of creating inline
// androidGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterGridView(this));

ImageAdapterGridView adapter = new ImageAdapterGridView(this);
androidGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then you can call `.notifyDataSetChanged` to refresh the view inside your onclick:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You can just do it once at the bottom of the `onClick` method.

---

Also you were creating a second adapter inside the click handler:

```
ImageAdapterGridView IAGV = new ImageAdapterGridView(mContext);
```

which was creating a new adapter completely, so you would have two adapters at that point, but one was not attached to the view.

---

One other small thing is it's name is somewhat confusing, since it's an adapter but named as though it were a view. I would maybe name it `ImageGridViewAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Could you elaborate what you mean by extracting it to a variable?  The ImageAdapterGridView IAGV = new ImageAdapterGridView(mContext); was just one of many attempts to call the adapter, I should have taken it out.

Comment: @SamDenton sure, added some more info

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot.  Thanks for telling me what was wrong with my method  instead of just posting correct code :)